# How do I calculate the generator of $\Bbb Z_{p}[x] /\langle f(x)\rangle $

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I find the generator of $\Bbb Z_{p} /\langle f(x)\rangle$ where p is prime and $ f(x) \in \Bbb Z_{p}[x] $ when I know the field order

I need to know how to find the generator of any field of that style.

Comment: It seems obvious, unless I misunderstand your question: the generator is the congruence class of $x$: $\xi=x+\langle f(x)\rangle$.

Comment: Do you mean the generator of the multiplicative group?

Comment: Yes, this is  @Lisyarus

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you know how to perform arithmetics in $F = \mathbb Z_p/\langle f \rangle$.

Now, the multiplicative group $G = F^\times$ has order $|G|=|F|-1$. For $g \in F$ to be a generator, we need $\operatorname{ord}(g)=|G|=|F|-1$. So, to check that $g$ is a generator, check that $g^{|F|-1}=1$ but $g^k \neq 1$ for all $k < |F|-1$.

Finally, there are $\phi(|G|)$ generators (since $G$ is cyclic), which is at least $\frac{|G|}{2}$. So, you can simply try random elements of $F$ and check if they are generators; you'll need $\frac{|G|}{\phi(|G|)}$ tries on average until you find a generator.